# Undefined reference to 'main' after adding a class to project

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, reference, program-entry-point

I'm having problems with a project written in Code Blocks.

I've made new console application and it builds.
But when I add a new class C::B throws me an error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o||In function `_start':
(.text+0x20)||undefined reference to `main'
```

I don't know what is wrong.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "display.h"

int main()
{
    Display newDisplay;
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**display.cpp**

```
#include "display.h"
#include <iostream>

Display::Display()
{
    std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl;
}

Display::~Display()
{
    std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
}
```

**display.h**

```
#ifndef DISPLAY_H
#define DISPLAY_H


class Display
{
    public:
        Display();
        virtual ~Display();

    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // DISPLAY_H
```

Comment: How many code files do you have? How did you add the class (some Codeblocks dialog used?)

Comment: Show your code, compilation options, and link options.

Comment: Obviously you don't have a `main` function defined.

Comment: Adding a new class using Code::Blocks will not cause that error.  Something else happened.  A cat walked on your keyboard, perhaps.

Comment: I don't have a cat :P
I made whole project step by step as I saw in YouTube video.
New Project -> build&run //OK
Add class ->build&run //ERROR
:((

Comment: @KrajeScS that was a good edit.  There's nothing wrong with any of that code though.  Nothing you've described should cause that problem.  Has main.cpp possibly been removed from the project?  Does "Rebuild" work?

Comment: I haven't removed anything from the project.
Rebuild doesn't work.

PS. Sorry for bad question editing.

Comment: Check the files that are passed to the linking phase.  Looks like your `main.o` is not passed to the linker.

Comment: OK. I rebuilded each file individually and it works. For now at least.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have the same problem, it happens after each added class. A workaround is to close and open the project, it works fine immediately after that.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using 13.12 on 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04.
I get the same problem and it does seem to be the class addition dialog that is to blame.
Use it to create the class files but **Don't** add it to the project.
Right click the project title in the 'Projects' tab (left pane in window) and use the 'Add Files' from the context menu.
Should compile ok then.

Before adding the new class this was a typical compile line :

```
g++ -Wall -g -I/media/Data/programming/source/wxWidgets-3.0.2/build/ubuntu14.04/debug/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0-d -I/media/Data/programming/source/wxWidgets-3.0.2/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread  -c /media/Data/programming/projects/wx/Xperiments/XperimentsApp.cpp -o ./bin/Ubuntu14/debug/XperimentsApp.o
```

After adding a completely empty class 'MyFileTree' the compile line for the new class becomes :

```
g++ -Wall -g -I/media/Data/programming/source/wxWidgets-3.0.2/build/ubuntu14.04/debug/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0-d -I/media/Data/programming/source/wxWidgets-3.0.2/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread -I -c /media/Data/programming/projects/wx/Xperiments/MyFileTree.cpp -o ./bin/Ubuntu14/debug/MyFileTree.o
```

Takes a while to spot the difference doesn't it?

What's that stray -I just before the -c switch?

It doesn't show up in the build options dialog or anywhere else i've been able to find so if it gets in there, how do you remove it?
It may be something to do with the wxconfig script that i'm using for setting the options - but nothing has changed in it's invocation so far as I can see.
It's unchanged from :

```
/media/Data/programming/source/wxWidgets-3.0.2/build/ubuntu14.04/debug/wx-config --cflags --debug=yes
```

As I said, **Don't** add to project via the class creation dialog do it manually using the management window.

Comment: I'm not sure if Google indexes comments, but I got this error following Bucky's C++ Programming Tutorials - 15 - Placing Classes in Separate Files on Youtube.  I am also running Ubuntu (14.04) and code blocks (13.12).  This answer fixed my error.

Comment: I'm a total noob, but this tripped me up when I followed this answer.
When you define the class, there is a File Policy section with a "Add paths to project".  Checking or unchecking this box does not affect the outcome of the answer provided by accoder.  
The Add to Project dialog box pops up after clicking Create in the Create New Class dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem today.

Solved it using Projects-> Build Options-> Search Directories

then set the compiler and linker options to "use project options only"